# How to get argument of a function which caused an exception

Tags: python, exception

Lets say I the following code:

```
def myDecorator(func):
  def wrapper(self):
    try:
      func(self)
    except Exception as e:
      print "The argument of the function was:" # print "Some Text"
      raise
  wrapper.__name__ = funct.__name__
  return wrapper


@myDecorator
def do_something(self):
  do_something_again("Some text")
```

My question is: How can I display the argument which was given to the function "do_something_again" inside my "except" block?

Answer (score 0):

Print `str(e)` to get the additional information. Example in your case:

```
def myDecorator(func):
  def wrapper(self):
    try:
      func(self)
    except Exception as e:
      print "The argument of the function was:", str(e)
      raise
  wrapper.__name__ = funct.__name__
  return wrapper
```

Comment: This will print the exception name, not "Some Text"